# How to save foreach loop values in a variable and print it outside of the loop?

Tags: php, loops, foreach, concatenation

I am trying to email a student list.
Student list data saved already in a database.

So I created a query to retrieve the data according to the `merchTxnRef`

then retriveing the row from the table/record and assign it to a variable..

and then concatenate the variable to the mail body and trying to send them.

but my `<tr></tr>` is empty in the mail.. I know it is because of I am saving the foreach loop variable incorrectly to this variable `$studentList`

how can I save the foreach loop values in a variable and print it outside of the loop

Following is the code I am trying.

```
$sqlListst = "SELECT * FROM tck_paymentStudents WHERE merchTxnRef LIKE $merchTxnRef'";

$resultListst = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $resultListst as $resultsListst ) {

        $merchTxnRef = $resultsListst->merchTxnRef;
        $sudentname = $resultsListst->sudentname;
        $admissionnmbr = $resultsListst->admissionnmbr;
        $purpose = $resultsListst->purpose;
        $amount = $resultsListst->amount;
        $grade = $resultsListst->grade;

        $studentList = '<tr><td>'.$merchTxnRef.'</td><td>'.$sudentname.'</td><td>'.$admissionnmbr.'</td><td>'.$purpose.'</td><td>'.$amount.'</td><td>'.$grade.'</td></tr>';
}
    $mail_body_guest_full  = '<table>';
    $mail_body_guest_full .=  $studentList;
    $mail_body_guest_full .= '</table>';

    $email = 'myemail@examplsite.com';
    $subject = 'Student List';
    $from_guest = 'guestemail@gmail.com';
    $headers_guest = array('From: My Site <'.$from_guest.'>');

    $mail_sent_guest = wp_mail( $email, $subject, $mail_body_guest_full, $headers_guest );
```

Comment: $studentList.= '<tr><td>'  not just equal to . use dot equal to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Missing concatination dot near `$studentList.=`

2) Missing single quotes in query near LIKE `'".$merchTxnRef."'";`

3) As per your comment `$wpdb->get_results($sqlListst)`

```
      $sqlListst = "SELECT * FROM tck_paymentStudents WHERE merchTxnRef LIKE '".$merchTxnRef."'";
      $resultListst = $wpdb->get_results($sqlListst) or die(mysql_error());
       foreach( $resultListst as $resultsListst ) 
       {
        $merchTxnRef = $resultsListst->merchTxnRef;
        $sudentname = $resultsListst->sudentname;
        $admissionnmbr = $resultsListst->admissionnmbr;
        $purpose = $resultsListst->purpose;
        $amount = $resultsListst->amount;
        $grade = $resultsListst->grade;

        $studentList.= '<tr><td>'.$merchTxnRef.'</td><td>'.$sudentname.'</td><td>'.$admissionnmbr.'</td><td>'.$purpose.'</td><td>'.$amount.'</td><td>'.$grade.'</td></tr>';
       }
        $mail_body_guest_full  = '<table><tbody>';
        $mail_body_guest_full .=  $studentList;
        $mail_body_guest_full .= '</tbody></table>';

        $email = 'myemail@examplsite.com';
        $subject = 'Student List';
        $from_guest = 'guestemail@gmail.com';
        $headers_guest = array('From: My Site <'.$from_guest.'>');

        $mail_sent_guest = wp_mail( $email, $subject, $mail_body_guest_full, $headers_guest );
```

Comment: this one was not an issue - `Missing single quotes in query near LIKE '".$merchTxnRef."'";`
and 1) was on issue and another main issue was 1$wpdb->get_results($sql)` is incorrect.. as per my query it should be `$wpdb->get_results($sqlListst)`